# CSS div postion absolute with variable height to expand container

Tags: html, css

I have searched and looked for several posts that looked similar to my problem, however I did not find an answer that got me closer to a solution.

So I am a little stuck with a DIV setup, I have a Container that surrounds two DIVs. The first DIV will have a logo that should be always postioned at top left (positioned that one relative). Now the Second DIV should always start at the bottom right of the Container, having some variable Text (positioned that one absolute).

If the Text in the second DIV is short, everything is fine, however if the Text is getting larger and gets larger than the logo, the Text will grow outside the top of the Container.

My goal would be that the Container grows with the absolute DIV, if the Text is getting larger.

I have setup a little fiddle to show you my problem.

```
[jsfiddle.net/jb3drnb0][1]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: have a look at my answer isit what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for all your suggestions. It gave me a different view on the problem. I tried the floating, it was close but not perfect. Sidd's suggestion with Javascript finally brought me to try the CSS Calc function and use Inline-Blocks with a Width-Parameter, and using text-align and vertical-align to achieve what I wanted.

So here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jb3drnb0/2/) for everyone who's interested. :)

```
.container { position: relative; height: auto; border: 1px solid #00f; overflow: visible; }

.left { display: inline-block; width: 160px; height: auto; vertical-align: top; }

.right { display: inline-block; height: auto; width: calc(100% - 170px); vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right; }
```

Comment: While this worked in your scenario, it doesn't fix the issue in the posts subject, as the solution no longer uses `display: absolute` :-(

Comment: You can easily use `display: absolute` with my code, you just need to add a position and width to the conatainer then.

Look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bkvyhL01/) to see an example.

However, nowadays using Flexbox is a much easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jb3drnb0/1/)
the css:

```
.container {  height: auto; border: 1px solid #00f; overflow: visible; }

.left { float: left; height: auto; }

.right { float: right; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; padding-left: 160px; height: auto: }
```

the html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        ******************<br/>
        **** TESTTEXT ***<br/>
        ******************
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have set the property height:auto. Replace it with for example 250px and check it
Code :

```
height : 250px;
```

Replace with :

```
height : auto;
```

Comment: if the text length is long it will fall out again. height must be auto

Comment: it does. it works on IE 5+: [http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)

Answer (score 0):

An absolutely positioned element will not give its height to the parent element container. So it's not possible to do this with pure CSS, as you must know either the width of `.left` (to give `.right` left-padding of that size - this would also require floating both inner divs)  or the height of `.right` (so you can assign it to `.container`).

But if you have the option to use Javascript it's easy to do:

```
    var ht = document.querySelector('.right').getBoundingClientRect().height;
    document.querySelector('.container').style.minHeight = (ht+10)+"px";
```

Here I calculate the height of `.right` after rendering, and give `.container` a height that is 10px more than that.

Comment: I tried that, didn't work for me - but if you have a working example or code I'd love to see it and correct my answer!